# Haskell: composing function with two floating arguments fails

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I am trying to compose a function of type `(Floating a) => a -> a -> a` with a function of type `(Floating a) => a -> a` to obtain a function of type `(Floating a) => a -> a -> a`. I have the following code:

```
test1 :: (Floating a) => a -> a -> a
test1 x y = x

test2 :: (Floating a) => a -> a
test2 x = x

testBoth :: (Floating a) => a -> a -> a
testBoth = test2 . test1
--testBoth x y = test2 (test1 x y)
```

However, when I compile it in GHCI, I get the following error:

```
/path/test.hs:8:11:
    Could not deduce (Floating (a -> a)) from the context (Floating a)
      arising from a use of `test2'
                   at /path/test.hs:8:11-15
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating (a -> a)) to the context of
        the type signature for `testBoth'
      or add an instance declaration for (Floating (a -> a))
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `test2'
    In the expression: test2 . test1
    In the definition of `testBoth': testBoth = test2 . test1
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Note that the commented-out version of `testBoth` compiles. The strange thing is that if I remove the `(Floating a)` constraints from all type signatures or if I change `test1` to just take `x` instead of `x` and `y`, `testBoth` compiles.

I've searched StackOverflow, Haskell wikis, Google, etc. and not found anything about a restriction on function composition relevant to this particular situation. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
   \x y -> test2 (test1 x y)
== \x y -> test2 ((test1 x) y)
== \x y -> (test2 . (test1 x)) y
== \x -> test2 . (test1 x)
== \x -> (test2 .) (test1 x)
== \x -> ((test2 .) . test1) x
== (test2 .) . test1
```

These two things are not like each other.

```
   test2 . test1
== \x -> (test2 . test1) x
== \x -> test2 (test1 x)
== \x y -> (test2 (test1 x)) y
== \x y -> test2 (test1 x) y
```

Comment: Thank you. Clear and concise. I haven't seen the (test2 .) notation before but it must mean f |-> test2.f.

Comment: @gdj: In Haskell, a binary operator can be partially applied to form a [section](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that; just never seen it used with "." but it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're problem doesn't have anything to do with `Floating`, though the typeclass does make your error harder to understand.  Take the below code as an example:

```
test1 :: Int -> Char -> Int
test1 = undefined

test2 :: Int -> Int
test2 x = undefined

testBoth = test2 . test1
```

What is the type of testBoth?  Well, we take the type of `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and turn the crank to get:

1. `b ~ Int` (the argument of `test2` unified with the first argument of `(.)`)
2. `c ~ Int` (the result of `test2` unified with the result of the first argument of `(.)`)
3. `a ~ Int` (`test1` argument 1 unified with argument 2 of `(.)`)
4. `b  ~ Char -> Int` (result of `test1` unified with argument 2 of `(.)`)

but wait!  that type variable, 'b' (#4, `Char -> Int`), has to unify with the argument type of `test2` (#1, `Int`).  Oh No!

How should you do this?  A correct solution is:

```
testBoth x = test2 . test1 x
```

There are other ways, but I consider this the most readable.

Edit: So what was the error trying to tell you?  It was saying that unifying `Floating a => a -> a` with `Floating b => b` requires an `instance Floating (a -> a)` ... while that's true, you really didn't want GHC to try and treat a function as a floating point number.

Comment: Thanks, this is an intuitive explanation. When I left out the typeclass, that must have meant that testBoth would take x and pass it to test1, then take the resulting function f : y |-> x and pass it to test2, which would then return f. That's clearly not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with `Floating`, but with the fact that you want to compose a function with two arguments and a function with one argument in a way that doesn't typecheck. I'll give you an example in terms of a composed function `reverse . foldr (:) []`.

`reverse . foldr (:) []` has the type `[a] -> [a]` and works as expected: it returns a reversed list (`foldr (:) []` is essentially [`id`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id) for lists).

However `reverse . foldr (:)` doesn't type check. Why?

#### When types match for function composition

Let's review some types:

```
reverse      :: [a] -> [a]
foldr (:)    :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
foldr (:) [] :: [a] -> [a]
(.)          :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

`reverse . foldr (:) []` typechecks, because `(.)` instantiates to:

```
(.) :: ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
```

In other words, in type annotation for `(.)`:

- `a` becomes `[a]`
- `b` becomes `[a]`
- `c` becomes `[a]`

So `reverse . foldr (:) []` has the type `[a] -> [a]`.

#### When types don't match for function composition

`reverse . foldr (:)` doesn't type check though, because:

```
foldr (:) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Being the right operant of `(.)`, it would instantiate its type from `a -> b` to `[a] -> ([a] -> [a])`. That is, in:

```
(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

- Type variable `a` would be replaced with `[a]`
- Type variable `b` would be replaced with `[a] -> [a]`.

If type of `foldr (:)` was `a -> b`, the type of `(. foldr (:))` would be:

```
(b -> c) -> a -> c`
```

(`foldr (:)` is applied as a right operant to `(.)`).

But because type of `foldr (:)` is `[a] -> ([a] -> [a])`, the type of `(. foldr (:))`  is:

```
(([a] -> [a]) -> c) -> [a] -> c
```

`reverse . foldr (:)` doesn't type check, because `reverse` has the type `[a] -> [a]`, not `([a] -> [a]) -> c`!

#### Owl operator

When people first learn function composition in Haskell, they learn that when you have the last argument of function at the right-most of the function body, you can drop it both from arguments and from the body, replacing or parentheses (or dollar-signs) with dots. In other words, the below 4 function definitions are *equivalent*:

```
f a x xs = g ( h a ( i x   xs))
f a x xs = g $ h a $ i x   xs
f a x xs = g . h a . i x $ xs
f a x    = g . h a . i x
```

So people get an intuition that says “I just remove the right-most local variable from the body and from the arguments”, but this intuition is faulty, because once you removed `xs`,

```
f a x = g . h a . i x
f a   = g . h a . i
```

are *not equivalent*! You should understand when function composition typechecks and when it doesn't. If the above 2 were equivalent, then it would mean that the below 2 are also equivalent:

```
f a x xs = g . h a . i x $ xs
f a x xs = g . h a . i $ x xs
```

which makes no sense, because `x` is not a function with `xs` as a parameter. `x` is a parameter to function `i`, and `xs` is a parameter to function `(i x)`.

There is a trick to make a function with *2* parameters point-free. And that is to use an “owl” operator:

```
f a x xs = g . h a .  i x xs
f a      = g . h a .: i
  where (.:) = (.).(.)
```

The above two function definitions are equivalent. Read [more on “owl” operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873529/596361).

#### References

Haskell programming becomes much easier and straightforward, once you understand functions, types, partial application and currying, function composition and dollar-operator. To nail these concepts, read the following StackOverflow answers:

- On [types and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28842096/596361)
- On [higher-order functions, currying, and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616619/596361)
- On [Haskell type system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617785/596361)
- On [point-free style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733739/596361)
- On [`const`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677316/596361)
- On [`const`, `flip` and types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31625335/596361)
- On [`curry` and `uncurry`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28618546/596361)

Read also:

- [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940382/596361)
- [Haskell function composition (.) and function application ($) idioms: correct use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3030675/596361)