# Tuple and function composition

Tags: haskell, tuples, function-composition

Is there a better way to express `(\(a, b) -> a < b)` with function composition? I feel like I'm missing something and experimenting with `curry` only confused me more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`curry` is the wrong thing to use here; it turns a function operating on tuples into a curried function. You want the opposite, which is [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:uncurry):

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

In this case, it's `uncurry (<)`.

(Another useful source for combinators useful in writing functions on tuples is [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html); since `(->)` is an instance of `Arrow`, you can read `a b c` as `b -> c`.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the types is the best way in Haskell to get the first idea, what any function does:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

`curry`: function of pair → curried function (it [curries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a function).

`uncurry`: curried function → function of pair.

> [Haskell Wiki page on currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) has small exercises at the end of the page:
>
> - Simplify `curry id`
> - Simplify `uncurry const`
> - Express `snd` using `curry` or `uncurry` and other basic Prelude functions and without lambdas
> - Write the function `\(x,y) -> (y,x)` without lambda and with only Prelude functions
>
> Try to solve these exercises right now, they will give you a massive insight into Haskell type system and function application.

There are several interesting applications of `uncurry`, try to pass different arguments to functions below and see what they do:

```
uncurry (.) :: (b -> c, a -> b) -> a -> c
uncurry (flip .) :: (b -> a -> b1 -> c, b) -> b1 -> a -> c
uncurry (flip (.)) :: (a -> b, b -> c) -> a -> c
uncurry ($) :: (b -> c, b) -> c
uncurry (flip ($)) :: (a, a -> c) -> c

-- uncurry (,) is an identity function for pairs
uncurry (,) :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
uncurry (,) (1,2) -- returns (1,2)
uncurry uncurry :: (a -> b -> c, (a, b)) -> c
uncurry uncurry ((+), (2, 3)) -- returns 5

-- curry . uncurry and uncurry . curry are identity functions
curry . uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
(curry . uncurry) (+) 2 3 -- returns 5
uncurry . curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
(uncurry . curry) fst (2,3) -- returns 2

-- pair -> triple
uncurry (,,) :: (a, b) -> c -> (a, b, c)
uncurry (,,) (1,2) 3 -- returns (1,2,3)
```