# Function Composition Types

Tags: haskell

I struggle understanding function composition type results e.g

```
ghci> :t (id . const)
(id . const) :: a -> b -> a
ghci> :t ((:) . (+))
((:) . (+))  :: a -> [a -> a] -> [a -> a]
```

How do you guys generally derive function composition types?

Comment: By doing what you did - use ghci, why do it by hand?

Comment: @alternative But how often is it really this simple task? I rarely start off with `(id . const)` and ask "what is its type"; rather, I have some hole in my code shaped like `a -> b -> a` and need to figure out some function that fits in that hole. Being able to reason about the types produced by `.` helps a lot, going in either direction.

Comment: @amolloy that is the opposite of this problem.

Comment: @alternative: yeah, and it's the way more relevant problem. Deducing the type of a given expression is a compiler task. Finding a suitable implementation (proof!) to fit a given type is a programmer task.

Comment: @leftaroundabout and again, thats not what the problem is asking, so its not relevant at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see that

```
> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So in general:

1. Given two functions. Consider them as curried functions of one parameter, i.e. function of type
   `a -> b -> c -> ... -> z` we'll consider as a function `a -> ( b -> c -> ... -> z )` of one parameter that returns function with one parameter less.
2. Result type of second function should be same as parameter type of first. So consider parameter of first function as result parameter of second. Denote it as **`b`**.
3. Result type of whole composition should be equal a function from parameter type of second function (denote it as **`a`**)  to result type of first function (denote it as **`c`**)

#### `> :t (id . const)`

```
> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

rename it to `x -> x`

```
> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
```

Note that `a` here is not necessary the same that in previous type equation, some rename it to `y -> z -> y`

```
a = y
b = z -> y = x
c = x = z -> y
```

So result is `a -> c = y -> ( z -> y)` same as `a -> b -> c`
Overall semantics is equal to `const`

#### `> :t ((:) . (+))`

```
> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

rename it to `x -> [x] -> [x]`

```
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

rename it to `Num y => y -> y -> y`

```
a = y
b = y -> y = x
c = [x] -> [x] = [y -> y] -> [y -> y]
```

Also we have restriction with type class `Num y`
So overall type well be `Num y => a -> c = y -> [y -> y] -> [y -> y]` same as `Num a => a -> [a -> a] -> [a -> a]`
Overall semantics is *"make single parameter function that adds first parameter to numeric value and prepend that function to a given list of single parameter functions"*

Answer (score 2):

That's simple, initially write down the types of both the functions:

```
> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

`(id . const)` gets translated to `\x -> id (const x)`

```
(const x)          :: b -> a      -- (Note that the type of `x` is `a` here)
id (const x)       :: b -> a      -- The output of id type will be the same as the input it takes
\x -> id (const x) :: a -> b -> a -- We aleady know the type of x
```

You can follow the same step for the next function.

Answer (score 2):

**Exercises:** Find the types of the function compositions below, by hand, not using GHCi. Do these exercises to build intuition for reasoning about function types. Remember that type `a -> a`, where `a` is a type variable, matches not only `Int -> Int` or `[Bool] -> [Bool]`, but `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` too. If you can't do the exercises, read below.

1. `(*3) . (+2)` (easy)
2. `(*) . (+2)`
3. `(:) . (+2)`
4. `(:) . (*)`

What is a [function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function)? It's something, that takes an input and returns an output. Not just random output, but output that depends on that input. For the same input the same function always returns the same output. A function transforms some stuff to another stuff. Input and output can be of different [types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type). So imagine a function as a magical one-way tube: you put one thing in the hole labeled **in** and get something else from another hole named **out**, possibly of entirely different form. Like, you put a tomato in a tube and get a machine gun from the opposite end. But remember, functions are one-way, you can't put anything in the function's **out** hole.

```
a :: Int -> Int -- take a thing of type Int and return a thing of type Int
a n = n + 2

b :: Int -> Int 
b n = n -- a function can even return the same value

c :: Int -> Bool -- an output can be of different type than input
c n = n `mod` 3 == 0
```

Haskell supports [higher-order functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function) and is [curried](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) by default. This means that there are no multiple-argument functions in Haskell, every function accepts only 1 argument, but sometimes they can return functions. Haskell tubes always has one and only one hole **in**, but sometimes tubes pop tubes from the hole **out**! There are even tubes, in which you can put other tubes. Function types are right-associative, which means that `a -> b -> c` and `a -> (b -> c)` are *the same thing*.

```
:t (+) -- Num a => a -> a -> a
:t (:) -- a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So what's a [function composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition)? It's when you compose functions into a new function, or when you fuse 2 tubes together, welding 1<sup>st</sup>'s **out** to 2<sup>nd</sup>'s **in**, so that whatever you put into the first tube's **in** hole, falls through and pops out of second tube's **out** hole.

A composed function then can be imagined as a long tube made out of two shorter tubes welded together. What would be the type of a composed function? Our new tube still has 2 holes in it, one labeled **in**, another labeled **out**. But remember, **in** of our new tube corresponded to **in** of a first part, and **out** of our new tube corresponded to **out** of the second part. So the type will be from whatever was input to 1<sup>st</sup> function to whatever was output of 2<sup>nd</sup> function.

```
:t (:[2,3]) . (+1) -- Num a => a -> [a]
-- why?
:t (+1)     -- Num a => a -> a
:t (:[2,3]) -- Num a =>      a -> [a]
```

We joint 2 functions together, first's output to second's input, and get a new function that still has one input and one output. And that's exactly what function operator's type says:

```
:t (.) -- (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Due to a historical accident, function composition goes from right to left, so `(*3) . (+2)` is a function that first adds 2 to a number, and then multiples by 3 the result. So how to deduce a type of a function composition? You joint the the input of 2<sup>nd</sup> function to an output of 1<sup>st</sup> function and throw away the types in between.

```
a -> b
     b -> c   becomes
a    ->   c
```

**See also:** [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616619/596361), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617785/596361), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28618546/596361), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677316/596361) for more ideas on how to use function composition and how to reason about function types.