# const function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The function `const` is defined in Prelude as:

```
const x _ = x
```

In GHCi, when I tried

```
Prelude> const 6 5  -> Gives 6
```

But when I tried

```
Prelude> const id 6 5 -> Gives 5
```

Even after making changes like

```
Prelude> (const id 6) 5 -> Gives 5
```

Shouldn't this function give `6` as the output of function `id` has type `id :: a -> a` which should bind like

```
Prelude> (const 6) 5 -> Gives 6
```

Why does function `const` behave differently?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that this is equivalent to `const (id 6) 5`, where `id 6` evaluates to 6, but it isn't. Without those parentheses, you're passing the `id` function as the first argument to `const`. So look at the definition of `const` again:

```
const x _ = x
```

This means that `const id 6 = id`. Therefore, `const id 6 5` is equivalent to `id 5`, which is indeed 5.

Comment: Another nice property is that `const id` = `flip const`

Comment: @danr, I have used `const id` several times, always thinking it seemed a terrible way to express the concept, without ever realizing that `flip const` would do the trick. That is indeed much easier to understand.

Answer (score 14):

Functions can also be parameters to other functions. **id** becomes a parameter of **const**.

What the expression **(const id 6) 5** really does is:

> (const id 6) 5
>
> (const id _) 5 -- grab the first parameter **id**
>
> id 5
>
> 5

For more detail about what operators really do:

1. Anything in a pair of brackets would be treated as a whole expression (but it doesn't mean it will be calculated first). For example: **(map (1+) )**, **(\x -> (-) x )**
2. Prefix operators bind stronger than infix operators
3. The left-most prefix operator in an expression would be treated as a function which grabs parameters (including other prefix operators) in an expression from left to right until facing infix operators or the end of line. For example, if you type **map (+) id 3 const + 2** in GHCi, you will get an error that says "The function `map' is applied to four arguments..." because **map** grabs **(+)**, **id**, **3** and **const** as parameters before the infix operator **+**.

Answer (score 6):

[Chuck is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9062340/596361), function application in Haskell is [left associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), meaning that a function invocation like `f a b c` is equivalent to `(((f a) b) c)`. Remember, in Haskell you should always practice looking at types of functions and trying to infer what a function can and can't do based on its type. At first you might fail to deduce anything from a function type, but with more experience type information will become indispensable.

What is the type of `const`? Enter `:t const` in GHCi. It will return `const :: a -> b -> a`. `a` and `b` are [type variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_variables_instead_of_concrete_types), meaning that const will accept an argument of *any* type. As 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> arguments have different types, you can pass practically everything to the function:

```
const 1 2 -- returns 1
const 'a' 1 -- returns 'a'
const [1,2,3] "a" -- returns [1,2,3]
```

There might've been specific [typeclass constraints](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) on type variables of `const` that would prevent passing functions, like `Num` or `Ord`, because a function isn't an instance of these typeclasses. In other words, a function doesn't behave as a number or an ordered thing, so `f + g` or `f < g` don't make sense. But `const` has no typeclass constraints that would stop us from passing functions as arguments. Remember that Haskell supports [higher-order functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function)? This means that Haskell's functions can accept and return other functions. Therefore:

```
const (+) (*) -- returns (+)
const head tail -- returns head
const id 2 -- returns id
```

`const` just ignores the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument and returns whatever was passed as a 1<sup>st</sup> argument, be it a Char, String, Integer, Maybe, [], some very complex algebraic data type, or even a function.

If the type of `const` is `a -> b -> a`, can you guess the type of `const 'a'` without finding it out without typing `:t const 'a'` in GHCi? To find out a type of `const 'a'`, substitute the type of the 1<sup>st</sup> argument in place of all same type variables, then remove the first argument from the type.

1. `a -> b -> a`: original type
2. `Char -> b -> Char`: substitute new type in type variables a
3. `b -> Char`: the type of a new function by removing the 1st argument from type declaration

What is the type of `const id` then?

1. `a -> b -> a`: original type
2. `(a -> a) -> b -> (a -> a)`: substitution
3. `b -> (a -> a)`: resulting type (first argument removed)
4. `b -> a -> a`: same as above, `->` operator is [right-associative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application)

**Exercise:**

1. Try to figure out mentally or with pen and paper, without using GHCi, what are the types of: `const (+)`, `const head`, `const tail`, `const (++)`, `const map`
2. Try to find out what arguments would you pass to the above functions to get a concrete value.