# need to know what <*> <$> and . do in haskell

Tags: haskell

What are these operators doing?

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I don't have any idea when I see the signatures. Perhaps some example with a simple and easy to understand explanation will help me.

Comment: For the first two see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030675/haskell-function-composition-and-function-application-idioms-correct-use

Comment: BTW, `(.) = (<$>)`, so you only need to learn two of them ;)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Only in the `(->) r` functor :).

Comment: @FUZxxl `(<$>)=fmap` and certainly `fmap` isn't the same as `(.)`. adamse is correct.

Comment: Try https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: One of the reasons Haskell is underrated is because of its smug references to category theory. To a programmer, `fmap` or simply `map` makes lot more sense than `<$>`. Good code is supposed to read like natural language, not like a phone book.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am also learning Haskell, and my recommendation is to have a look into [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), and more precisely:

- for `(.)` read [Function composition](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition)
- for `<$>` and `<*>` read [Applicative functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)

In essence:

- `(.)` is function composition: if you have `g :: a -> b` and `f :: b -> c` then `f . g` is essentially `f(g(x))`: first use `g` on an `a` to get a `b` and then use `f` on that `b` to get a `c`
- `<$>` takes a function taking an `a` and returning a `b`, and a functor that *contains* an `a`, and it returns a functor that *contains* a `b`. So `<$>` is the same as `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`
- `<*>` takes a functor that *contains* a function taking an `a` and returning a `b`, and a functor that *contains* an `a`, and it returns a functor that *contains* a `b`. So `<*>` kind of *extract* the function from a functor and applies it to an arguments also inside a functor, and finally returns the result into a functor

**Note** the explanations that you find in the book chapters are better than my attempt above

Comment: [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html#binary.functor) and the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) are also good sources for this question after reading LYAH.

Answer (score 25):

Maybe you learn via examples (like I do), so here are some simple ones you can mess around with in GHCI.

```
(.) - Function Composition 
-- (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
> f = (+1)
> g = (*2)
> a = f . g
> a 0
1 -- f( g( 0 ) ) or (0 * 2) + 1
> b = g . f
> b 0
2 -- g( f( 0 ) ) or (0 + 1) * 2


<$> - Functor
-- (<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> a = (*2)
> b = Just 4
> a <$> b
Just 8


<*> - Applicative
-- (<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> a = Just (*2)
> b = Just 4
> a <*> b
Just 8
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Here is another example   ([(*2), (+10)] <*> [1,2,3])  == [2,4,6,11,12,13]

Answer (score 3):

The `(.)` operator composes functions. For example, `\x -> f (g x)` is the same as `f . g`. You can do this for arbitrary functions, e.g. `\x -> f (g (h x))` equals `f . g . h`.

The `<$>` and `<*>` operators are not defined in terms of functionality. Their functionality depends on the actual type `f` that they are applied on. The `<$>` operator is an alternative for the `fmap` function in the `Functor` library. For example, for the `Maybe` type it takes the left operand and only applies it if the right operand is a `Just` value. So in order to find out what these operators do, just have a look at the implementations for the specific types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a a newbie to Haskell and sometimes Haskell type declarations confuse me, too.

It's easy to get lost at first because the tutorial says that the `Capitalization` naming convention is usually for type declaration and the `camelCase` naming convention is usually for variable.

Actually, this belongs to a higher technique in Haskell, may be polymorphism. Just think of `f`, `a` and `b` as some kind type variables - *variables that handle type*. And `class` in Haskell is not for Object like OOP but for `type`. So `Functor f` means that type `f` belongs to `class Functor` and so on.

If you replace these letter `a`, `b`, `c` with some type - *called* `instance` - for example `String` `Int` `Char`. It will make sense:

```
(.) :: (Int -> Char) -> (String -> Int) -> String -> Char
(<$>) :: Functor Maybe => (String -> Int) -> Maybe String -> Maybe Int -- type `Maybe` belongs to class `Functor`
...
```

Answer (score 0):

While the common uses of `<$>` and `<*>` is obscured by the fact that they are in a typeclass, you can usually read the haddock documentation for this information.  Use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%2a%3E) if you have a hard time finding to which module a function belongs.