# Why is the $! operator right-associative?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, associativity

I'm just learning Haskell and I'm still not entirely clear on when and how strict evaluation is forced

When I want a function to evaluate its arguments strictly I find myself writing

```
((f $! x) $! y ) $! z
```

which seems weird.  Shouldn't $! be left-associative so I could write

```
f $! x $! y $! z
```

and have it do what I want?

Am I completely misunderstanding the $! operator?

Comment: Why not just write a function `!$` with the reversed fixity of `$!` that does what you want?

Comment: The question is why the function isn't already defined that way.  I want to know if my desire to write it that way reflects a misunderstanding of how things in Haskell work.

Comment: If you're just learning Haskell I don't think you should be messing with strict application.  It's very rarely needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Argument against

I found a proposal from 2008 in haskell-prime to make the `$` and `$!` operators left-associative:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ChangeDollarAssociativity

There is only one argument against the proposal: "This would break a *lot* of code".

## Arguments in favour

Instead, there are given **four arguments in favour of left-associative `($)`**, the last one being the same as yours, and considered the most important. They are, in short:

- 0) given the expression `f x y`, with two applications, we would be able to write `f $ x $ y`
- 1) now, with right associative `($)`, we can write `f . g . h $ x` as `f $ g $ h $ x`,

  however: `\x -> f $ g $ h $ x ==> f $ g $ h` is invalid,

  so that writing such pipelines with composition is better, as it allows easier cleanup of code
- 2) Left associative ($) allows you to eliminate more parentheses, in addition to the ones eliminated with (.), for instance:

  `f (g x) (h y) ==> f $ g x $ h y`
- 3) your argument: the right associative version of `$!` is inconvenient because of giving rise to things like: `((f $! x) $! y) $! z` instead of `f $! x $! y $! z`

## Conclusion

I give support to use the better left-associative version of application operators redefining them at the beginning of our code, like this:

```
import Prelude hiding (($), ($!))

infixl 0  $, $!
($), ($!) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b  
f $  x =         f x
f $! x = x `seq` f x
```

Comment: Older (2006), similar discussion in Haskell Cafe (he tells: "the associativity of $ is just plain wrong"): http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg12549.html

Comment: To translate an expression in the conventional style `f $! g $! x` with the cited tactic for plain `$` , one would need some sort of strict composition: `f .! g $! x`. I wonder: is there such operator already defined in a library?

Comment: BTW, the current `<$>` is consistent with the current conventional `$`: `f <$> g <$> x` seems to be equivalent to `f . g <$> x`. But another, left-associative version of `<$>` wouldn't make much sense, because consuming several Applicative arguments is written as `f <$> x <*> y` or `g <*> x <*> y` (for a pure `f` or an Applicative `g`). It seems that `<*>` is already left-associative (as wanted for `$` in Haskell-prime), and lower priority than `<$>`.

Comment: It seems that `<$>` is left-associative [in the latest base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-) (so, inconsistent with the conventional `$`), contrary to what I said in the above comment. But my `<$>` from an older base I have on my system is right associative! (`show <$> show <$> Just 3` gives `Just "\"3\""` for me; or [I don't understand what is happening, so I asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30911093/94687))

Comment: Yes, there exists `(.!)`: [Strict composition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun-1.1.0.1/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html#g:3).

Answer (score 11):

It's to mirror the fixity of `$`.  You could make a very good case for both `$` and `$!` having the wrong fixity.

Comment: What is $?  I googled "haskell operators" but none of the first couple google links mention it (even the one that's a PDF file containing a list of haskell operators).  Neither has the book I'm reading mentioned it so far (Real World Haskell).  Is there a list of all Haskell operators somewhere?

Comment: @dspyz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign/1290727#1290727

Comment: @dspyz You'll even find a [link to the author of Real World Haskell commenting on its use in the book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030675/haskell-function-composition-and-function-application-idioms-correct-us) in Thomas' comment.

Comment: Sorry, I should ask my questions one at a time.  Where can I find a list of Haskell operators?

Comment: The Prelude operators are in the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#prelude-fixities).

Comment: @dspyz Do note that there's no such thing as a list of Haskell operators.  Is `*%^*%^*&&$&%^` a Haskell operator?  Well, it could be, if some library defined it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant pre-defined operators

Comment: @dspyz To search for Haskell operators and functions by name try [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) (uses a limited set of packages, but can also search by type which is very useful) or [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) (searches only by name, but in all of Hackage.)

Comment: @dspyz FP Complete's Hoogle searches a larger number of packages than the regular Hoogle, so it can be handy https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle