# Does Julia have an operator similar to Haskell's dollar sign?

Tags: haskell, julia

Haskell's dollar sign is a wonderful function that for `f $ g`, for example, `f` is evaluated with the results of `g` as its argument. This can work brilliantly like this

```
sin $ sqrt $ abs $ f 2
```

Which is equivalent to

```
sin(sqrt(abs(f(2))))
```

The dollar sign is nice to me because it is more readable. I have noticed that Julia has `|>` which pipelines. This seems to do `f |> g` meaning that `g` takes the evaluated result of `f` as an argument. From what I have noticed, it seems that I could write the aforementioned expression like this

```
2 |> f |> abs |> sqrt |> sin
```

But I was wondering if there was some operator such that I could do something like what I did in Haskell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One can define the `$` operator (as long as you don't need its deprecated meaning of xor) locally in a module;

```
f $ y = f(y)
```

However, the associativity of this operator (it is left-associative) is incorrect, and its precedence is too high to be useful for avoiding brackets. Luckily, there are plenty of right-associative operators of the right precedence. One could define

```
f ← x = f(x)
```

(a single line definition, almost Haskell-esque!) and then use it thus:

```
julia> sin ← π
1.2246467991473532e-16

julia> exp ← sin ← π
1.0000000000000002

julia> exp ∘ sin ← π
1.0000000000000002
```

Comment: This caught me by surprise! I thought we had to use the functional notation: `←(f, y) = f(y)`.

Comment: Wow! This is quite the find.

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful! What are the limitations on characters to use, though? (Obviously, `f Q x = f(x)` doesn't work. `extra token "Q" after end of expression`)

Comment: @HarrisonGrodin The allowed operators are defined [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia-parser.scm).

Answer (score 15):

There's now a [function composition operator](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base.html#Base.:%E2%88%98) on the unstable nightly version (soon to be in 0.6). It can be used on earlier versions with the [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) package.

```
help?> ∘
"∘" can be typed by \circ<tab>

  f ∘ g

  Compose functions: i.e. (f ∘ g)(args...) means f(g(args...)). The ∘ symbol can be
  entered in the Julia REPL (and most editors, appropriately configured) by typing
  \circ<tab>. Example:

  julia> map(uppercase∘hex, 250:255)
  6-element Array{String,1}:
   "FA"
   "FB"
   "FC"
   "FD"
   "FE"
   "FF"
```

Or, with your example — note that you need parentheses here:

```
julia> (sin ∘ sqrt ∘ abs ∘ f)(2)
0.9877659459927356
```

Comment: And note that, in Haskell, it would [often be more idiomatic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3030675/237428) to write `sin . sqrt . abs $ f 2`, where `.` is the same as Julia's `∘`, so they're even more similar :-)

Comment: Or he can just define it himself as a stopgap solution: `∘(f::Function, g::Function) = (xs...) -> f(g(xs...))`. While not certain how it works in Haskell, note that you can now define a new compound anonymous function like this: `h = f∘g`. When I tried to do `cos $ sin` with no input in Haskell, I got an error.

Comment: @DNF that's because `$` in Haskell is function application (`f $ x = f x`) rather than function composition, which is written as `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`.