# Order of evaluation and type check with ($)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn how the ($) operator works. I run

```
(+5) ($)  7
```

I get

```
 * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b.
              (Num (a -> b), Num ((a -> b) -> a -> b)) =>
              a -> b
```

Could anyone help me understand why I get this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like (+) is the prefix form of +.

($), called function application, is the prefix form of $.

```
> (+) 1 2 == 1 + 2
True
```

So if you want to apply (+5) to 7 then ($) would do that in this syntax

```
> ($) (+5) 7
12
```

which is equivalent to

```
> (+5) $ 7
12
```

Note that $ is most often used to [simplify syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030675/haskell-function-composition-and-function-application-idioms-correct-us).

Answer (score 0):

I should have done

```
(+5) $  7
```

I still not sure I understand the difference.

Comment: The difference is that `(+5) ($) 7` applies the function `(+5)` to the two arguments `($)` and `7` (which makes no sense), whereas `(+5) $ 7` applies the operator `$` to the two arguments `(+5)` and `7` (which does make sense).

Comment: When using ($) make sense ?

Comment: `($)` would only make sense if you wanted to use `($)` as a value, for instance if you wanted to pass the function `($)` as an argument to some other function. (Although there aren’t too many times where you would want to do that.) For instance, `fmap ($) [1,2,3]` is equivalent to `[($) 1, ($) 2, ($) 3)]`. **EDITED**

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, `($)` makes sense in exactly the same situations in which `(any operator)` would make sense. `(+5) ($) 7` makes about as much sense as `5 (+) 7` would. But if you wanted to use the function `($)` as a value — e.g. if you want to pass it as an argument — then you should use `($)` rather than `$`.

Comment: @bradrn `zipWith ($) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]` is one useful example.